# Problems upgrading Nuget application - Digital Signature Mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I attempt to upgrade a NUGET package, for example Productivity Power Tools, I get a Download and Install messagebox that says "Digital Signature Mismatch".
The message also says;

### The installed version of 'Productivity Power Tools' is signed but the update version has an invalid signature. Therefore Extension Manager cannot install the update.

### If you trust the update, try the installation again after you uninstall the installed version.

On the latter point I take the advice and it works.
But this problem is one I have with the Nuget Package Manager as well. I am wondering if I will get this on every package upgrade.

Does anyone else have this problem, and does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581019) acknowledged that **it's a bug in Windows XP**.

As of the release date of that support article (February 2012), they say that **you have to manually uninstall and reinstall the extension**. Or you can go through some convoluted process described there to get a hotfix (maybe a good idea if you have multiple machines).

Answer (score 8):

For the nuget signature mismatch:

1. Close all visual studio 2010 instances.
2. Open visual studio again as administrator
3. Go to "Tools" > "Extension Manager"
4. Uninstall NuGet
5. Install NuGet again.

if you are not able to uninstall it go to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager

and remove this folder.
**deleting this is at your own risk!**

Comment: Yep! Uninstall re-install worked perfect on mutiple machines with the same issues.

Comment: Worked perfectly, great tip. Seems more than a little ridiculous that this problem exists for NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing NuGet packages with Visual Studio Extensions.

Productivity Power Tools is an extension and managed through Extension Manager. It has nothing to do with NuGet.

If you have problems updating or uninstalling extensions, you should run Visual Studio as Administrator, then uninstall the extension. Restart VS but run as a normal user and try re-installing the extension. This should allow you to update extensions in the future without running as Administrator.

Hope this helps.